# Emulator says Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)?? what should i do

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-emulator, emulation

i'll get this error....what should i do to run my emulator...

```
11-05-2018 
16:17   Gradle sync started

16:17   Project setup started

16:17   Gradle sync finished in 14s 711ms (from cached state)

16:22   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

16:22   Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSE4.2 POPCNT

16:22   Emulator: Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!

16:22   Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

16:22   Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

16:22   Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

16:22   Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

16:22   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\Parth\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_23.avd/userdata.img

16:22   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

16:22   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

what is this error mean? and what i have to do for fix this...i use emuator of nexus 5x api 23

Comment: Hi, i have same problem. My workspace is vmware windows 10 x64 and emulator not working. Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: I found my solution. AVD Settings -> Edit Image set Graphics to GLES 2.0